# DisplayLink 1.4 and Ubuntu 17.10 on XPS-13 laptop, not seeing monitor

Tags: external-monitor, displaylink

I've followed the instructions that I've found on this site and others, but still not seeing output (except the AOC startup logo) on the  monitor.

```
tac@tac-xps13:~/Downloads$ lsusb -d 17e9:
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17e9:ff10 DisplayLink 

tac@tac-xps13:~/Downloads$ lsmod | grep -E "drm|video"

uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 evdi,i915
syscopyarea            16384  2 evdi,drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  2 evdi,drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  2 evdi,drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   356352  27 evdi,i915,drm_kms_helper
video                  40960  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
```

When I go to Settings | Displays, I don't see it there either, just the primary screen on the laptop.  Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Any updates on this?